# How to get rid of spying app (rooted)

Tags: root-access, malware, cleanup

My android phone is installed with spyware (spying app). This can be a breach for my business leaking out passwords.

How to clean wipe android OS and freshly install Android OS again cleanly.

My system is rooted.

Phone Model : Samsung A7 2018.

Comment: Android phones are embedded device which work totally different that a regular PC. Therefore there is not "the one solution", instead it depends on your phone manufacturer and phone model. Please edit your question and add more details on your phone.

Comment: Is the 'spyware' pre installed or someone installed it??

Comment: @Aayush Hi, Someone installed it.

Comment: I am not familiar with Samsung phones, you can perform a factory reset or if you want to re-install the OS to make sure install a factory image via Odin software.

Comment: The model names of Samsung are not unique, there are three device variants for you model name:  SM-A750F/DS (EMEA); SM-A750G (Hong Kong); SM-A750FN/DS (Europe). For finding the correct firmware you have to identify your device exactly.

Comment: @Robert Can I expect the model mention somewhere on my device?? or on box?

Comment: @Robert I mean where can I find the model variant on my device/box ??

Comment: @Robert Hi, I just found my model variant online... below are the details of my Samsung A7 2018   ....     Model SM-A750F
Model name Galaxy A7 2018
Country 

India (INS)
Version Android 9
Changelist 16070901
Build date Wed, 19 Jun 2019 09:53:33 +0000
Security Patch Level 2019-06-01
Product code INS
PDA A750FXXU1BSF4
CSC A750FODM1BSF4

Comment: @Robert Firmware details are clear at this link    https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-a7-2018/firmware/SM-A750F/INS/download/A750FXXU1BSF4/278069/

Comment: @Robert Hi. Good Evening! Any help in finding the exact firmware and  working on it will be appreciated. I'm stuck not using my phone. I'm not willing to give the phone to a service center to do this job! I want to clean install everything with right process all by my myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to download the firmware using [Samloader](https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy/) and then install it using "Odin".

Answer (score 0):

It's called "flashing the stock ROM".  Look for the firmware for your particular model (N, FD, etc.) at https://www.sammobile.com/  There are pretty good instructions at https://www.getdroidtips.com/samsung-galaxy-a7-2018-stock-firmware/

(If you still want the phone to be rooted, you'll have to root it again - the stock ROM isn't rooted, it's what you got when you first got the phone.)

Comment: Hi @Rukbat. Thanks for the comment. will one be able to get firmware directly from Samsung or Google (google being android developer)?? Sammobile.com is some unknown site which even I provided the links too. How can one get all that is required from original manufacturer or android os developer (google)?

Comment: No, but there are sites you can get the firmware from.  Just google _flash stock rom_ and the model number of your phone.  Or check on SamMobile.